# Web service to get near by road on giving Latitude Longitude

Tags: reverse-geocoding

Is there a web service available which on providing a Latitude and Longitude can give the nearest road with its type i.e. whether the road is a highway or district road?

Google reverse geo-coding just gives type route but no further classification.

Comment: I have never used it before, but I think you can use the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).  I saw some examples where you can search for roads by a bounding box, but you could get that by making a small buffer around your point and getting the extent.  I'm not sure what kind of attributes you can get back though.

Comment: Geonames might be your solution example http://api.geonames.org/findNearestIntersectionOSM?lat=37.451&lng=-122.18&username=demo

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ['nearest' endpoint](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/pull/397) of GraphHopper. Then once you have the road ('edge') you can fetch all properties you stored before e.g. the name or with [this pull request](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/pull/730) also the type.

Or do you mean something like [map matching](https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching)? (Note, I'm the author of the GraphHopper routing engine)

Another possibility is a reverse geocoder which includes this information e.g. [photon](https://github.com/komoot/photon) as `"osm_key":"highway","osm_value":"tertiary"`